# Jquery Execution is not working completely in the first load of a pgae , but working after refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery code that exicute after the `done` function of one `ajax call`  which replace some html attributes value

```
  <div class="0-div" data-thumb="11.jpeg">
   <a class="0-a" href="test.html" ><img class="0-img" src="11.jpeg" /></a>
 </div>

 <div class="0-div" data-thumb="21.jpeg">
   <a class="0-a" href="test1.html" ><img class="0-img" src="21.jpeg" /></a>
 </div>

 <div class="0-div" data-thumb="tes.jpeg">
   <a class="0-a" href="test.html" ><img class="0-img" src="tes.jpeg" /></a>
 </div>

 <div class="0-div" data-thumb="zoo.jpeg">
   <a class="0-a" href="test.html" ><img class="0-img" src="zoo.jpeg" /></a>
 </div>


 <script>
   $.ajax({..Ajax code.}).done(function(msg){
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

                        $("."+i+"-div").attr('data-thumb', "pa.jpg");
                        $("."+i+"-a").attr('href', "new.html");
                        $("."+i+"-img").attr('src', "sa.jpg");
                    } });
</script>
```

Actually this code is working but it is slow.

For example if I load the page first time `data-thumb` & `href` are replaced correctly but the img `src` is not changed.

But when I refresh the page then img `src` also changing.

How to solve this?

> Note : i found the same situation in
>   [jQuery script not executing on initial page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763548/jquery-script-not-executing-on-initial-page-load#answers-header)
>   . But here i don't know how to apply this .

Please help .

Comment: provide your actual code sample to understand it more accurately

Comment: If you want to increase performance, don't use jQuery. It's already well documented how slow it can be for changing DOM elements.

Comment: *"for example if iake the page"* "iake" is not an English verb. I can't begin to guess what you meant there. When asking for help, have the courtesy to at least read over what you've written (the preview area is located between the text box and the Post Your Question button for a reason, after all) to make sure it's clear and has all necessary information.

Comment: so what is the other solution ?

Comment: "but it is slow" - define "slow." Just how many matching elements are there? There'd have to be **thousands** for the code above to take any appreciable time (and despite what @lix says above, it would with the DOM as well; with the code above, if it's slow, jQuery is not the problem).

Comment: "if I take the page" doesn't make any sense. Take it where? Please update your question  with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button).

Comment: @lix citation needed.

Comment: Are you sure the issue is image being pulled from the server VS being pulled form the cache? So  you think it is slow, but actually the cache is what is making it faster the second time?

Comment: @Pointy Pure Javascript to access the DOM can be faster as you can cut the overhead that jQuery has on this.

Comment: sorry for the delay . i edited the question . Please check .

Comment: Yes, but generally the performance difference is minor. In this case it looks like there are only a dozen changes being made.

Comment: now i provided all the code . please check now .

Comment: abilasher - The code quoted is not what's slow. See @epascarello's comment above, by far the most likely thing is that loading the images is slow.

Comment: but i think the actual issue is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763548/jquery-script-not-executing-on-initial-page-load#answers-header .. but how to solve this

Comment: @epascarello please check the updated question

Comment: if you wait some time, does the image actually change eventually? Bear in mind, you can change the "src" attribute instantly but it won't necessarily swap the image visually until the new one downloads. If your image downloads really are slow, then either shrink them (if that's acceptable), or improve your network speed, or improve the processing power of your client and/or server. Of course ideally you'd work out which one was actually the problem before investing in this.

Answer (score 0):

You might not need jQuery.
Assign and use `#id` to the elements instead of `.class`:

```
<div id="0-div">...</div>
```

IDs are designed to be unique and performance is much better.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    var url   = image_array[i];
    var thumb = document.getElementById(i + "-div");
        thumb.setAttribute("data-thumb", url);
    var link  = document.getElementById(i + "-a");
        link.href = url;
    var image = document.getElementById(i + "-img");
        image.src = url;
}
```

**Changes:**

- Removed unnecessary jQuery library usage. I prefer to use native Javascript solutions. After all, everyone who is familiar with JS can understand this code, but not all know custom libraries. As well, these are additional dependancies which worsen your page performance.
- You are getting `image_array[i]` three times. It's better to allocate it once and reuse.
- It's clear what you assign to variables with distinctive names such as `url`, `image`, etc.
- Switched to `getElementById` instead of jQuery's query selector. This might improve performance as you do not need to parse the query and ids are unique.

**Suggestions:**

- If there can't be another HTML element with exactly same parameters, use `#id`. Please note you can use `.class` alongside with `#id`: `<div class="thumbnail" id="thumbail-0">`.
- As you've seen in previous suggestion, use more meaningful identificators. There's a huge difference between `<div id="0-div">` and `<div class="thumbnail" id="thumbnail-0">`.
- Use wrappers. Wrap your contents in a div instead of randomly scattering them in DOM:

Layout practice:

```
<!-- Bad -->
<div id="0-div">
<div id="0-a">
<div id="0-b">
<div id="1-d">

<!-- Good -->
<div class="product" id="product-0">
    <div class="thumbnail" id="thumbnail-0">...</div>
    <a class="link" id="link-0" href>...</a>
    <img class="preview" id="image-0" src>
</div>
```

This way you can easily style it:

```
.product { /* Style the container */ }
.product .thumbnail { /* Style the thumbnail */ }
.product .link { /* Style the link */ }
```

Comment: i will check this